# How do I pass a stripe token from angularjs to nodejs or fix error nodejs post?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to setup stripe payments but running into an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at /Users/andreykondratyuk/websites/talllly/src/server/app.js:56:37
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]...

**The form:**

```
<form stripe-form="stripeCallback" name="checkoutForm">
        <input ng-model="number" placeholder="Card Number" payments-format="card" payments-validate="card" name="card" />
        <input ng-model="expiry" placeholder="Expiration" payments-format="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" name="expiry" />
        <input ng-model="cvc" placeholder="CVC" payments-format="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" name="cvc" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div ng-if="checkoutForm.card.$invalid"> Error: invalid card number! </div>
      </form>
```

In the controller

```
// Stripe Response Handler
       $scope.stripeCallback = function (code, result) {
         console.log(result);
          if (result.error) {
            window.alert('it failed! error: ' + result.error.message);
          } else {


  // Simple POST request example (passing data) :
    $http.post('/charge', result)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
    });
      }
  };
```

On the backend app.js

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
console.log(req);
    var stripeToken = req.body.token.id;

    var charge = stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 10000, // amount in cents, again
        currency: "usd",
        card: stripeToken,
        description: "email@email.com"
    }, function(err, charge) {
        if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
        res.send("completed payment!");
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token id is on the response body as `id`, there is no token object returned by the stripe.js call, check the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js).

So in Node your line:

```
var stripeToken = req.body.token.id;
```

should be:

```
var stripeToken = req.body.id;
```